# Objects of same class have the same properties even though declared differently when pushing segue

Tags: ios, swift

I've been stuck trying to fix an issue in my application that prevents me from getting my desired result.

When pushing segue to the next view controller, I passed two objects of the same class to `var original:[Person] = []` and `var edited:[Person] = []`

```
if (segue.identifier == "showSummary") {

    let vc = segue.destination as! SummaryViewController
    vc.original = myObject
    vc.edited = Bill.calculateBill(myObject, switchServiceCharge.isOn, switchGST.isOn)
    vc.gst = (switchServiceCharge.isOn, switchGST.isOn)
}
```

Before `calculateBill`, the original value of a property inside is 11.

The `calculateBill` is a class function in another class Bill:

```
class func calculateBill(_ bill: [Person],_ svcCharge: Bool,_ GST: Bool) -> [Person] {

    var mutableBill = bill

    for i in 0 ..< mutableBill.count {

        for j in 0 ..< mutableBill[i].items.count {

            let tax = Bill.getGSTForIndividual(mutableBill[i].items[j].itemPrice, svcCharge, GST)
            mutableBill[i].items[j].itemPrice += tax
        }
    }

    return mutableBill
}

class func getGSTForIndividual(_ individualAmt: Decimal,_ svcCharge: Bool,_ GST: Bool) -> Decimal {

    var taxCost : Decimal = 0.00
    let SERVICE_CHARGE = Bill.getServiceCharge() //0.10
    let GOODS_SERVICE_TAX = Bill.getGST() //0.07

    if (svcCharge && GST) {

        taxCost = individualAmt * SERVICE_CHARGE
        taxCost = taxCost + ((individualAmt + taxCost) * GOODS_SERVICE_TAX)
    }
    else if (!svcCharge && GST) {

        taxCost = individualAmt * GOODS_SERVICE_TAX
    }
    else if (svcCharge && !GST) {

        taxCost = individualAmt * SERVICE_CHARGE
    }
    else {

        taxCost = 0.00
    }

    return taxCost
}
```

When I did a `print()` to test whether the properties inside are different, they both yield the same results somehow...

```
print(original[0].items[0].itemPrice) //12.947000000000000123904, originally 11
print(edited[0].items[0].itemPrice) //12.947000000000000123904
```

What exactly is going on and why do both the objects have the same properties even though I have declared them differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `Person` is probably declared as a `class`, not a `struct`. This means that it's a reference type, and when you:

```
var mutableBill = bill
```

you're not actually making a copy of `bill`, but rather another reference to the same object. So, when you change the properties on `mutableBill`, you also change the properties on `bill`, since they both point to the same object.

The solution is to make an actual copy of `bill`. The two options are either to declare `Person` as a `struct`, in which case you will always get a copy, or else to make an initializer on `Person` that takes another `Person` and initializes itself using the passed-in `Person`'s properties:

```
init(person: Person) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, the struct solution worked. I'm relatively new to OOP and this is the first time I encountered such a problem.